# Serial Port Constant Monitoring in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I have a program then when started looks for the serial ports available on the computer and if found would try to open those and listen to those for data.

As of now, I have a configuration file that has got all port settings along with the Port Number to listen to.

At first run I get the user to first enter the POrt No. on which the device is connected. That is recorded into the Config and is used from there one.

I would now like to change that so that when started, it scans the ports and gets the list of Serial Ports available. That part I can do with SerialPort.GetPortNames() method.

However, now I would like to ping each port and check which one has the device connected, open that port and keep listening to that port.

I can check with my device manufacturer to get the commands to ping and ACK back from device.

My Question to the experts is

1. Is it correct (archietecturally/technically) to keep the ports open all the time
2. Should that be done in a seperate thread and probably keep the thread for just serial port communications while main thread does all other jobs.
3. What if there are multiple devices connected to same PC. Should we keep seperate threads for each device ?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ashutosh

Comment: You cannot do any of this when you have no idea what kind of devices are connected to the machine.  And you don't, there is no device discovery mechanism.  It is outright lethal if you start sending commands to a motor controller.

Comment: I do have the idea about the devices connected. However the program when starts need to know this automatically without me telling it to start looking for the devices. Also, the software is meant for a very certian specific device+PC setup so I am confident that IF there is a device attached, its gonna be THAT device only.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct (archietecturally/technically) to keep the ports open
>   all the time

It's normal to do that. Continually opening and closing ports is an expensive and wasteful operation.  Sometimes is is used as a message framing protocol, ie. open/send/close, but a protocol that keeps the port open is surely going to perform better.

> Should that be done in a seperate thread and probably keep the thread
>   for just serial port communications while main thread does all other
>   jobs.

It can be, yes.  I have used such a design - create threads that attempt to open COM1-COM9 and, if the open succeeds, try to communicate with a peripheral.  If the comms is successful, the handler thread messages the main thread with an object reference/pointer that can be used to communicate with the port, (and usually give user feedback, eg. check a checkbox and change its background colour from red to green).

> What if there are multiple devices connected to same PC. Should we
>   keep seperate threads for each device ?

That's how I usually handle it, yes.  I define a class that represents the port, it's protocol and state.  Each port-handler thread then creates its own instance and so each port gets handled independently.